# he has been so for the last ten years

Tags: grammaticality

Is he the prime minister?

a. Yes. He has been for the last ten years.

b. Yes, He has been so for the last ten years.

I think response (a) is grammatical and response (b) is not. It seems to me that "so" cannot be used with a noun (prime minister).

Am I correct?

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct. (A) is what we say and (B) doesn't sound right. "He has been such for the last ten years" is correct grammatically, but is rather outmoded. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+been+such+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20such%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20such%20for%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Another possibility is "he has been that for the last ten years".

Comment: Both are correct, depending on where you live (this is why I'm not putting this in an answer). The American heritage dictionary says this for so: "pron. Such as has already been suggested or specified; the same or roughly the same: She became a loyal friend and remained so." So can be used as a pronoun as described.

Comment: How many questions can you ask about the word 'so'? I've counted 3 that you've asked in the past 3 hours.

Comment: This question was asked two and a half years ago, and none of my recent questions is about 'so'.